# zsh - alias with no space at the end of the invocation

Tags: shell, alias, zsh

I would like to have an alias like:

```
alias gra-bitbucket="gra origin https://gismoranas@bitbucket.org/gismoranas"
```

so that I can use it like:

```
gra-bitbucket/some-repo.git
```

to add a new origin to a git repository (gra is a [oh-my-zsh!](http://ohmyz.sh/) alias).

My issue is that I don't want to have to write the whole url each time. It must not be an alias, but it would be nice to have a one liner setting.

Comment: Err. Waitaminute. When you say "with no space at the end", you mean no space *in the invocation*? That's much harder than simply not inserting a space after alias-generated content in the generated command; it typically requires using your shell's command-not-found hook, which often isn't even possible when a command is qualified (contains '/'s).

Comment: ...if you think about it for a minute, it should be obvious why that's so (from the perspective of implementing shells efficiently): When your alias is guaranteed to be its own word, the tokenizer doesn't need to look at the alias list; rather, whatever word it generates can simply be evaluated against your hash table of aliases, your hash table of functions, etc -- each of these being an amortized-constant-time lookup if things are done well.

Comment: ...whereas when any leading substring can potentially be an alias, the pattern-matching is that much more expensive. One can minimize it with regex-y tools, but that's still a fair bit of extra work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Note that this is written for the original question, which did not disambiguate whether it specified "no space at the end" of the invocation of the alias, or no space between the alias-defined code and user-provided code in the invoked command.*

---

Don't use an alias for that; a function is the better tool.

```
gra-bitbucket() { gra origin https://gismoranas@bitbucket.org/gismoranas"$@"; }
```

If your shell were (an older version of) bash rather than zsh, you could need to use the `function` keyword to define a function with a dash in the name (which is disallowed under POSIX rules). Thus:

```
# this version works with bash as well (but not POSIX sh)
function gra-bitbucket { gra origin https://gismoranas@bitbucket.org/gismoranas"$@"; }
```

...or, if you want to be compliant with any POSIX shell, remove the `-` from the name (in this case, substituting a `_`):

```
# this version works with all POSIX shells
gra_bitbucket() { gra origin https://gismoranas@bitbucket.org/gismoranas"$@"; }
```

---

In all of these cases, usage (but for the name change in the POSIX form) is identical to what it would be for your desired alias, were that alias possible:

```
gra-bitbucket /some-repo.git
```

...would refer to `https://gismoranas@bitbucket.org/gismoranas/some-repo.git`

Answer (score 1):

Source: https://blog.sebastian-daschner.com/entries/zsh-aliases

Put the following in your .zshrc:

```
# blank aliases
typeset -a baliases
baliases=()

balias() {
  alias $@
  args="$@"
  args=${args%%\=*}
  baliases+=(${args##* })
}

# ignored aliases
typeset -a ialiases
ialiases=()

ialias() {
  alias $@
  args="$@"
  args=${args%%\=*}
  ialiases+=(${args##* })
}

# functionality
expand-alias-space() {
  [[ $LBUFFER =~ "\<(${(j:|:)baliases})\$" ]]; insertBlank=$?
  if [[ ! $LBUFFER =~ "\<(${(j:|:)ialiases})\$" ]]; then
    zle _expand_alias
  fi
  zle self-insert
  if [[ "$insertBlank" = "0" ]]; then
    zle backward-delete-char
  fi
}
zle -N expand-alias-space

bindkey " " expand-alias-space
bindkey -M isearch " " magic-space
```

Now you can do:

```
# command aliases
alias jj='java -jar'
alias mcp='mvn clean package'
...

# blank aliases, without trailing whitespace
balias clh='curl localhost:'
...

# "ignored" aliases, not expanded
ialias l='exa -al'
ialias curl='curl --silent --show-error'
...

# global aliases
alias -g L='| less'
alias -g G='| grep'
ialias -g grep='grep --color=auto --exclude-dir={.bzr,CVS,.git,.hg,.svn}'
```

---

#### Specifically, for your problem, the `balias` function defined above is what you need:

```
balias gra-bitbucket="gra origin https://gismoranas@bitbucket.org/gismoranas"
```

Comment: There's so much *extra* functionality in this answer that I can't tell where/how/whether it actually answers the question the OP asked at all.

Comment: So, someone asks "how do I do X?", and you answer "here's a library you can build things on"? If you don't show how to use that library to do X, that's not an answer to the specific question at all.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Specifically, just use balias instead of alias to do X.

Comment: That's what I was encouraging you to include, *explicitly*, in the body of the answer itself.