# Bash Alias/Function for passing an arg without preceding space

Tags: bash, function, alias

Here's what I have in my .bash_aliases:

```
function gga { git log --all --grep=$1; }
```

Here's a call, and its result:

```
gga "remove private"
fatal: ambiguous argument 'remove private': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

I've also tried

```
function gga { git log --all --grep="$1"; }

function gga { git log --all --grep='$1'; }

function gga { git log --all --grep="$@"; }
```

with precisely the same results.

And what I want to happen:

```
$ git log --all --grep="remove private"
commit 1916fca1a5609cec7474b5d507fa8760d4877648
...
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to do this? AFAICT I'm doing the thing suggested in [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36133855/zsh-alias-with-no-space-at-the-end-of-the-invocation)

Comment: Neither of the things you say you also tried with the same results will give the same results. Did you just mean they both still give an error? If they give you a different error message, please include that in your question.

Comment: No, they give exactly the same message. Character-for-character identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function gga { git log --all --grep="$@"; }
```

which was the first function I tried, was correct. All attempts were being shadowed by an alias.

Comment: As @chepner pointed out, you likely don't need the `$@` unless you have a different use case in mind. `$1` is correct.

Comment: There's no need for a question, let alone an answer, based on an unrelated misconfiguration. I'd delete both.

Comment: @chepner That's not true at all; this is not a special problem, and the flow that led to it is likely to be the first thing many users try. (That flow being: Make an alias -> alias doesn't work because it injects a space -> make a function, but forget to unalias -> get confused.)

Comment: @ffledgling: If you use $@, and it fails for some reason, the errors will be loud and somewhat explicable. If you use $1, and pass it an additional argument (possibly by accident, like `gga foo bar` instead of `gga "foo bar"`), then it will fail silently. Therefore, $@ is the better choice.

Comment: Better yet would be to simply *check* if there is more than one argument, since `git log` can take multiple arguments.

Comment: Why check when you can just handle it smoothly?

Answer (score 1):

The following code you tried should function as expected.

```
function gga { git log --all --grep="$1"; }
```

And then call it like so:

```
gga "remove private"
```

If it's not working as expected, please try running `type gga`, and see if the function definition matches what you defined. It also helps catching shadowing by other commands/aliases, etc.

It should return something like this:

```
$ type gga
gga is a function
gga () 
{ 
    git log --all --grep="$1"
}
```

Comment: Using `$@` as part of a larger string is usually not what you want. Here, `$1` should be sufficient, as the OP isn't passing more than one argument to `gga`.

Comment: I did. That had exactly the same result as the others.

Comment: @chepner I was in the middle of making that edit, it's fixed now.

Comment: @JacobKopczynski Are you re-sourcing the file if you're defining the function in a file? Does `type gga` give you the definition you expect?

Comment: Ah, it's shadowed by an alias. That makes way more sense.

Comment: @JacobKopczynski I'll add that to the answer